# How to calculate additional height of pyramid.

Tags: geometry

If you have a truncated pyramid and the rest of the pyramid above it, how do you calculate the height of the pyramid on top of the truncated one?

[image: Picture that describes problem]

I am pretty sure this formula comes from similar triangles, but I can't seem to get it:
$\ B : H^2 = B_1 : x^2 $ which then gives me: $\ x= \frac{\sqrt{B_1}H}{\sqrt{B}} $

$B$ is the bigger base and $B_1$ is the smaller base of the truncated pyramid.

Can somebody please help me? Where does the $\ \sqrt{B} - \sqrt{B_1} $ come from?

Comment: B is the bigger base and B1 is the smaller base of the truncated pyramid if anyone is confused.

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is the height of the truncated pyramid.
$x + H$ is the height of the full pyramid when the top is added on.

$\frac {B}{(x+H)^2} = \frac {B_1}{x^2}$

solving for $x$ gives

$x = \frac {\sqrt {B_1}}{\sqrt {B} - \sqrt {B_1}} H$

Not entirely relevant, but:

$V = \frac 13 (B^2 + BB_1 + B_1^2)H$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the volume ratio of the two similar pyramids is

$$\frac{\frac13 A_1x}{\frac13 A(x+H)}
=\frac{x^3}{(x+H)^3}$$

where $A_1/A =B_1^2/B^2$. Substitute the areas and simplify to get

$$\frac{B_1^2}{B^2}=\frac{x^2}{(x+H)^2}$$

Solve for x,

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{B_1}H}{\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{B_1}}$$